# inline-block breaks with many children

Tags: html, css

If I create a container div and then some div children (say three), and set the parent to display: inline-block, I get something like this [jsfiddle-good](http://jsfiddle.net/6qWg6/16/)

[image: proper inline-block functionality]

CSS

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 2px; 
    display: inline-block;
}

.child {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="child">child 1</div>
    <div class="child">child 2</div>
    <div class="child">child 3</div>

</div>
```

That's good! I want that. The problem arises when I have many children (say 30) [jsfiddle-bad](http://jsfiddle.net/6qWg6/17/)

[image: inline-block with extra white-space]

Why is that white-space spearing, and how do I get the container div to size down properly?

Comment: if you remove inline block and maybe use max-width and min-width it would size properly. just make sure to add a clearing element below all those cells to have the height expand to fit the contents.

Comment: @ChrisBrickhouse the container needs to resize according to a users window. If I set a max-width that's greater than the users window then I still have excess white-space.

Comment: There are also [ways to clear an element](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) without adding markup.

Comment: @Sabe You may want to hunt around for the term [CSS shrink wrap](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201303/how_to_shrinkwrap_and_center_elements_horizontally/). There are various ways to make an element fit the width of its child content, and each has pros and cons and potential compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

that space was there because the boxes could not fit in that space so I just added 10 to the width and no more space. here is a link to the code if need be:
http://jsfiddle.net/AnDrewpa18/t5Nth/

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="child">child 1</div>
    <div class="child">child 2</div>
    <div class="child">child 3</div>
    <div class="child">child 1</div>
    <div class="child">child 2</div>
    <div class="child">child 3</div>
    <div class="child">child 1</div>
    <div class="child">child 2</div>
    <div class="child">child 3</div>
    <div class="child">child 1</div>
    <div class="child">child 2</div>
    <div class="child">child 3</div>
    <div class="child">child 1</div>
    <div class="child">child 2</div>
    <div class="child">child 3</div>
    <div class="child">child 2</div>
    <div class="child">child 2</div>
    <div class="child">child 2</div>
    <div class="child">child 2</div>
    <div class="child">child 2</div>
    <div class="child">child 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.child {
    width: 110px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

Comment: the width of my container is variable. this answer would only work for a fixed-width container.

Comment: is the padding fixed too?